# SQL - Everything before a certain character; and if there character is not there

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set and I'm trying to get everything before the comma, or the data if there is no comma. Basically I am trying to get critera1. Here's what it looks like:

```
User1  criteria1,criteria2,criteria3 
User2  criteria1
User3  criteria1,criteria2
```

I've tried these 2 that I found I this site:

```
,LEFT([TURFS], CHARINDEX(',', [TURFS]) - 1) AS [TURF]
,REPLACE(LEFT(TURFS, CHARINDEX(',',TURFS)-1),',',' ')
```

but they come back with an error, and I'm guessing because some of my data rows do not have commas in them.

this is the error I get:
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: add a `where` condition `where CHARINDEX(',', [TURFS]) > 0` so only rows with atleast one `,` get evaluated.

Comment: CASE is your friend.

Comment: Also in the future, instead of just saying "it came back with an error", why not provide the error? That would certainly make it easier to fix your issue, no?

Comment: This is the error:Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Hi James, is this still open? Do you need further help? If this issue is solved, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a conditional:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [TURFS]) >0 then LEFT([TURFS], CHARINDEX(',', [TURFS]) - 1)
else
[TURFS] end as newValue
```

Comment: @JamesArroyo As you are new here please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to Kyle and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15  points border yourself you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation which makes a single call to `SUBSTRING` to obtain the result.  In case a comma be found, it takes everything from the first position up until, but not including, the comma.  If a comma be absent, it takes the entire field.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([TURFS],
                 1,
                 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [TURFS]) > 0
                      THEN CHARINDEX(',', [TURFS]) - 1
                      ELSE LEN([TURFS])
                 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(UserName VARCHAR(100),Crit VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('User1','criteria1,criteria2,criteria3')
,('User2','criteria1')
,('User3','criteria1,criteria2');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT UserName
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Crit,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS CritSplitted  
    FROM @tbl   
)      
SELECT UserName 
      ,CritSplitted.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Crit1
      ,CritSplitted.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Crit2
      ,CritSplitted.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Crit3
FROM Splitted
```

The result

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| User1 | criteria1 | criteria2 | criteria3 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| User2 | criteria1 | NULL      | NULL      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| User3 | criteria1 | criteria2 | NULL      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

### Attention

If your strings could include the *three characters of evil* you should do a `REPLACE` for `<, > and &` to `&lt; &gt; and &amp;`

### UPDATE

If you want the first value only you can reduce this to a one-liner:

```
SELECT UserName
      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Crit,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
FROM @tbl
```